# How to download excluded paths via composer?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

I want to install `doctrine/dbal` repository with `tests` and `docs` folders. But using `composer install` or `composer update` I cannot find a way how to do that?

They are excluded in `doctrine/dbal` -> `composer.json` file:

```
"archive": {
  "exclude": ["!vendor", "tests", "*phpunit.xml", ".travis.yml", "build.xml", "build.properties", "composer.phar"]
}
```

Is there any way to force that installation? 
I think there must be a way to download it and for example run tests on my local machine.

**Edit:**

I've also tried to use `require-dev` but after `composer update` there was no `tests` folder in `doctrine/dbal` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option `exclude` in the `composer.json` file has nothing to do with your problem anyway. This option is used when you make an archive out of your composer package.

### Why are some folders excluded then?

The folders `/docs` and `/tests` are excluded in the `.gitattributes` file:

```
/tests export-ignore
/docs export-ignore
.gitattributes export-ignore
.gitignore export-ignore
.gitmodules export-ignore
.travis.yml export-ignore
build.properties export-ignore
build.xml export-ignore
phpunit.xml.dist export-ignore
run-all.sh export-ignore
composer.lock export-ignore
```

### So how can I get them downloaded?

First of all there are two different sources where composer can get its data from when you `composer install` or `composer update`:

> **Dist:** The dist is a packaged version of the package data. Usually a released version, usually a stable release.
>
> **Source:** The source is used for development. This will usually originate from a source code repository, such as git. You can fetch
>   this when you want to modify the downloaded package.
>
> Packages can supply either of these, or even both. Depending on
>   certain factors, such as user-supplied options and stability of the
>   package, one will be preferred.

#### Composer's default

When your composer is in default configuration to use `stable` packages and the preferred install is `dist`.

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable"
```

Then composer downloads a zip file from github, which was created with the filters defined in `.gitattributes`. This makes composer faster.

#### Make composer download from source

If you like to have the sources you have two options.

1. Make the `"preferred-install": "source"`
2. Use the `--prefer-source` option on `composer update`

Both of them make composer to use `source` for *all* packages.
If you like to have only the sources of `doctrine/dbal` instead of the sources of all packages then use:

```
composer update doctrine/dbal --prefer-source
```

#### Note

You will have to delete the `doctrine/dbal` folder (or any folder you like to update from source) in your `/vendor` folder if it already exists to get it reinstalled.